# Packets differ in length after sending over tcp

Tags: sockets, tcp

when i send packets (each paket with 8192 bytes) over tcp the packets which i receive on client machine are different in length for ex 1460 or 568 bytes. and also the number of the packets are different but the data on client machine is complete. i tried with textfile, pdf and mp4.

i know that interrupted data will be resent on tcp connections but can only pieces of a package get lost or the hole packet? i mean when i send a packet with 8192 bytes the packet receive the client but with less data then i send it. i think the ack package only give back the last number of a package thats why i think data in the middle couldnt get lost. am i wrong?

Comment: The #1 way for people to "lose" data in a TCP stream is they didn't check the return value of write/send. You can tell write to write 8192 bytes. But it may only write 5000. You have to check for that and handle it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a packet in TCP. It is a byte stream protocol. There are no messages or message boundaries. A blocking read is only obliged to transfer at least one byte at a time. If you want messages, you must implement them yourself.

Comment: i know that i have to implement messages by myself. another try, when i send a buffered data stream and some of the data get lost, is all data from a single buffered stream lost or is it possible that the datasize only increases and the lost data will be resend in a later buffered stream

Comment: None of the data gets lost. If you're experiencing data loss, it is due to a bug in your code. Such as 'a later buffered stream' for example. You should use a single buffered stream for the life of the socket, at both ends.